# When should we write our own move constructor (move assignment operator)

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

A user-defined **move constructor** and **move assignment operator** could have been omitted in all examples explaining **move semantics** I have seen so far because compilers generated ones will do the job.

The answers I found in stackoverflow will not go beyond the "Rule of three" (Rule of five) - so if a class defines any of the following then it should probably explicitly define all five.

But for **copy constructor** and all other members the reason is obvious and an example could be written easily to show what issues can occur if user-defined copy constructor doesn't exist.

In wikipedia we can find:

> A user-defined copy constructor is generally needed when an object owns pointers or non-shareable references, such as to a file.

So the question is if there are examples that will show if user-defined move constructor or move assignment operator are really needed or I can assume that in 99% of cases compiler generated ones will be enough.

Comment: If any of the copy operations is declared, then none of the move operation will be generated. Therefore you will have to define them manually as least as `default`.

Comment: As you can read in [rule_of_three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), *"Unlike Rule of Three, failing to provide move constructor and move assignment is usually not an error, but a missed optimization opportunity."*

Answer (score 0):

I guess an example of necessary customized move operation is case of a class consisting of a container and some pointer(s) to its contents; say, a circular buffer with its head and tail.
But true, that's not that common to write.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an relative offset pointer type like [boost::interprocess::offset_ptr](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/interprocess/offset_ptr.html)
The implementation is essentially a bit-like:

```
template<class T>
class offset_ptr
{ 
   int64_t offset;
   T* operator*() 
   {
      return reinterpret_cast<T*>(this + this->offset);
   }
};
```

You can see that the value of the pointer (i.e. what it points at) depends not only on the offset member but on the value of "this". A very clever trick (and not entirely standard's conforming). A member-wise move would be a disaster as the new value of this would make the pointer point to the wrong location.